# scala.js - is js.Dictionary the right type for a "Map"

Tags: scala.js

I am using the Twilio Video javascript API with scala.js, for example, the conversations API: https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/releases/0.13.9/docs/Conversation.html

The API makes use of javascript "Map" objects (it creates them with javascript code like `new Map()`.)

The only way I've been able to get this to work in my scala.js object is with a js.Dictionary, something like:

```
@js.native
class TwilioConversation extends js.Object {

  var participants: js.Dictionary[TwilioParticipant] = js.native
```

Is that the right type to model a "Map", or is there a better one?
When I tried using scala Map/mutable.Map, it failed with a class cast exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not exactly the *right* type. The right type would be `js.Map`, but at the moment it does not exist yet. It still lives in a work-in-progress PR at https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/pull/2110/files#diff-4937cb9b8e89d2f21babe311012e63a1

Before it makes it into Scala.js proper, you have two options:

- Use `js.Dictionary` as you do, which will work as long as all you need to do is use String keys, and get/set values (because the public API for those operations is the same for a dictionary and a map).
- Define a `JSMap` in your codebase, like this: (inspired from the above-linked PR but without references to the `Iterable` and `Iterator` parts):

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js
import js.annotation._

@js.native
@JSName("Map")
class JSMap[K, V] extends js.Object {
  def size: Int = js.native

  def clear(): Unit = js.native

  def has(key: K): Boolean = js.native

  def get(key: K): js.UndefOr[V] = js.native

  def set(key: K, value: V): this.type = js.native

  def delete(key: K): Boolean = js.native
}
```

Comment: Good to know I'm not going crazy.